# Raspberry Pi openni USB interface not supported

Tags: ros, openni, raspberrypi, xtion, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have managed to successfully install ros groovy on my raspberry pi and openni. Unfortunately when I connect my Asus Xtion to the raspberry pi (with a powered hub), it does detect the sensor, but I receive and error of *USB interface not supported*. Is there any way that I can fix this error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62867/raspberry-pi-openni-usb-interface-not-supported/) by [cyrus](https://answers.ros.org/users/4885/cyrus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-05-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did not get it to work with OpenNI either but OpenNI2 works with some minor changes. It should compile out of the box from my repo using make:
https://github.com/kalectro/OpenNI2.git

I also wrote an openni2_camera package which runs on the raspberry and can stream the depth image as a ROS message with 30fps (when overclocked)
https://github.com/kalectro/openni2_camera

After building OpenNI2 successfully and catkin_make ran through, navigate into OpenNI2/Bin/ReleaseX and call rosrun openni2_camera openni2_camera_node from here. Otherwise it will not find the Openni2 libraries

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cyrus](https://answers.ros.org/users/4885/cyrus/) on 2013-05-16**:
I will definitely try this out soon. Thanks

**Comment by [danielq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4679/danielq/) on 2013-05-17**:
Could it work only with the Asus Xtion? or could also with the Kinect?

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-05-18**:
I did not get it to work with the Kinect

**Comment by [domikilo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8836/domikilo/) on 2014-03-14**:
@Kalectro: maybe your openni2 have a problem with calibration, I can not set using my calibration, it still use defaut calibration, but I am working with Linux Arm and the resolution of depth in ARM just 160*120, but with rgb it is 320*240. Do you know how to I fix it?